# MKNetworkKit how to append post data

Tags: mknetworkkit

I'm currently trying to switch from ASIHttpRequest to MKNetworkKit and Im having problems with the post data. How do I do the following in MKNetworkKit?

ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request appendPostData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"version\":%@,\"values\":[{\"device\":\"%@\",\"os\":\"ios\",\"version\":\"%@\"}]}", VERSION, [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier], [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

I'm just not sure how to append post data in MKNetworkKit. I found the addData method but that doesn't allow me to add the data like above with the extra data inside of the values {}.

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MKNetworkOperation *op = [self operationWithPath:INIT_URL params:body httpMethod:@"POST"    ssl:YES];
[op setPostDataEncoding:MKNKPostDataEncodingTypeJSON];//This is important
[op addCompletionHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation)
```

Answer (score -1):

Although I am quite new in this let me share with you what I am doing.

Firstly, I create the engine (where is the service that I call located).

In my interface:

```
@interface INGMainViewController (){
    MKNetworkEngine *engine_;

}
```

In my Initialization:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil

  {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            engine_= [[MKNetworkEngine alloc] initWithHostName:@"www.xxx.gr"];
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }
```

Then in the function that I'll call the service:

```
NSDictionary *formParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            theClientCode, @"ClientCode",
                            theContractNumber, @"ContractCode",
                            theAppleID, @"AppleID",
                            @" ", @"AndroidID",
                            @" ", @"WindowsID",
                            uid, @"AppleDeviceID",
                            @" ", @"AndroidDeviceID",
                            @" ", @"WindowsDeviceID",
                            theCellPhone, @"TelephoneNumber"
                            , nil];

    MKNetworkOperation *operation = [self.engine operationWithPath:@"/services/Authentication.ashx"
                                                            params: formParams
                                                        httpMethod:@"POST"];


    [operation addCompletionHandler:
     ^(MKNetworkOperation *operation)
     {
         NSLog(@" Operation succeds: %@", [operation responseString]);
     }
                       errorHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *errorOperation, NSError *error)
                        {
                           NSLog(@" Errors occured: %@", error);
                        }];
    [self.engine enqueueOperation:operation];
}
```

...and that is all.

Of course I still face some issues but i think there are not coming from the Kit.

I hope I have helped you.